# $S^TAS$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: positive-semidefinite

I need to prove this: 
If A is an n$\times$n positive semidefinite matrix, and S any $n \times m$ matrix, then $S^TAS$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you written down the definition of what it means for $A$ to be positive semidefinite? for $S^\top A S$ to be positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^TS^TASx=(Sx)^TA(Sx)$. Therefore, this quantity is $\ge 0$ by hypothesis on $A$.